# Do I need a Wings of Liberty code to play Heart of the Swarm?

Tags: starcraft-2

I have Wings of Liberty, but I am thinking of getting HoTS. My code for Wings of Liberty has been used on my locked account. So, my question is do I need another copy of Wings of Liberty to play HoTS, or would my copy be sufficient enough to play HoTS without Wings of Liberty being linked to my account?

Comment: Yes; you need wings of liberty to play heart of the swarm.  WOL is the base game.

Answer (score 3):

If your account is locked then you will need to do one of two things:

1. Get your account unlocked and then purchase the Heart of the Swarm Expansion.
2. Create a new account and purchase both Wings of Liberty and Heart of the Swarm. Since Heart of the Swarm is an expansion, you cannot purchase it and play it by itself.

Once you activate a key on a Blizzard account it is tied to that account. Licenses can't be transferred in the way you are describing above.

To answer the question in the comments (since it wasn't clear above), you can install from the DVD, however you will not be able to log into the game because it is still tied to your base Wings of Liberty account.

While you can purchase a HoTS key and install with it, you won't be able to play the game because when you log into the game with your new account with only the HoTS key it will see that you do not have a WOL key with the account.

Comment: I know about the License transferring thing. That's not my question. My question is could I use the Wings of Liberty disc to install then install the expansion to it without having Wings of Liberty linked to my account.

Comment: You can but you can nothing by doing so because multiple patches have been released and you still need to purchase the base game

Comment: You cant,it doesn't matter from where the game files are installed (DVD,downloaded,torrent...),what matters is the game key which in your case is used up on your old account.If you install the game again from dvd it will ask you to login or to enter your game key and create new account,if you try this it will say that the entered key is already used up with different account.

Comment: You should contact the support to retrieve your account,I got locked out of my age of conan account,fortunately I had my surname in the name of my e-mail address and was able to prove it by sending photos of my ID and game-box.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks. I will look into getting my account unlocked so I can play some Starcraft 2. Now, I heard your account can be locked if you change ISP's, which is probably what happened to me, and with all of the phishing emails I keep receiving, I probably deleted the email that I could unlock my account with thinking it was another phishing scam.